# retrieving asp membership username and email

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

bit of a sceptical question but is it possible to retrieve the username and email address from a user who is already logged-in whereby the user has been made from ASP.NET Login Controls/ASPNETDB.mdf?

This is my attempt..

```
public partial class Success : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MembershipUser userName;
    MembershipUser userEmail;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userName = Membership.GetUser(userName.UserName);
        userEmail = Membership.GetUser(userEmail.Email);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I can reword this any better but if you understood this, your help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You need to do something like
MembershipUser u =  Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

and then you can use u.Email or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like

```
MembershipUser u =  Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

and then you can use u.Email or whatever.

Comment: I have got the user name fine thanks to your solution however I'm still struggling to retrieve the email address. any other ideas?

Comment: string userEmail = u.Email; assuming that email field is not blank